# Dynamic Virtual Host with Dynamic Alias

Tags: apache, virtualhost, httpd.conf, mod-alias

I am using **DNSMasq** for this setup. I am having issues with Alias, as it does not work at all for dynamic virtual hosts. And there's no such a thing as `VirtualAlias` in Apache documentation.

I am trying to setup my new environment just like I did before for `.dev` tld, but I am having issues, because it require more configuration.

Here's fully functional `.dev` Virtual Document.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.dev
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/nn/Sites/%1"
</VirtualHost>
```

Here's fully functional configuration for single project in the new environment that I am trying to setup for all projects with VirtualDocumentRoot.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/nn/Sites/BaseApp/app"
    ServerName base.app

    Alias /scripts "/Users/nn/Sites/BaseApp/.tmp/scripts"
    Alias /styles "/Users/nn/Sites/BaseApp/.tmp/styles"

    <Directory "/Users/nn/Sites/BaseApp/.tmp">
        Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted

        ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
        ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
        ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

And here's the attempt to recreate it for all projects that may use new environment. ***(the one that I need help with)***

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.app
    UseCanonicalName Off
    VirtualDocumentRoot "/Users/nn/Sites/%1/app"

    Alias /scripts "/Users/nn/Sites/%1/.tmp/scripts"
    Alias /styles "/Users/nn/Sites/%1/.tmp/styles"

    <Directory "/Users/nn/Sites/%1/.tmp">
        Options FollowSymLinks Multiviews
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted

        ErrorDocument 403 /403.php
        ErrorDocument 404 /404.php
        ErrorDocument 500 /500.php
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

It is accessible, but it searches for `scripts` and `styles` in the `app` folder, so surely `Alias` is not working. Any tips, I am clueless?

Comment: Is  "fully functional configuration" and "one that I need help with" running at the same time? What version of apache?

Comment: Not running at same time. Server version: Apache/2.4.16 (Unix)

Answer (score 3):

After a very long research of 3 days and this question that nobody gave answer to, I figured following:

- `Alias` - Does not work for `VirtualDocumentRoot` but `DocumentRoot`
     only.
- `AliasMatch` - Does not work for `VirtualDocumentRoot` but
     `DocumentRoot` only.

Hence these two (`Alias` and `AliasMatch`) are not available for use when creating dynamic hosts.

I will update this answer if this gets resolved somehow with `mode_rewrite` as this seem like the only solution. Hopefully `Apache` creates:

- `VirtualAlias`
- `VirtualAliasMatch`

Someday in near future...

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: Nope. Never figured it out.

Comment: I'm in the same spot, been turning the web upside down. Can't find a solution.