# Create a dynamic alias in Apache?

Tags: php, apache, apache2.4

I am looking for a solution to create an alias for a varying path on the server determined by the subdomain name. Where the folder is behind the document root.

How can I make `http://*.site.com/images/` point to `/var/www/site/clients/*/images/`?

Something like:

```
Alias /images "/var/www/site/clients/$(var)/images/"
```

(Please note I am not looking into changing the document root to /var/www/site/clients/*/.)

```
<VirtualHost *.domain.tld:80>
  ServerName *.domain.tld
  DocumentRoot "/var/www/site/public_html"

  <Directory "/var/www/site/public_html">
    Options -Indexes
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
    AllowOverride All
  </Directory>

  Alias /images "/var/www/site/clients/*/images"
</VirtualHost>
```

Attempt #1 - Fails with 404:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([^.]+)\.
RewriteRule ^/images/(.*)$ /var/www/site/clients/%1/images/$1 [L]
```

Attempt #2 - Fails with 404:

```
SetEnvIf Host "^([^.]+)\." SUBDOMAIN=$1
Aliash /images /var/www/site/clients/%{env:SUBDOMAIN}/images
```

Comment: `AliasMatch` is your friend. 
 https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#aliasmatch

Comment: @Nic3500 Alright, but how do I squeeze in a wildcard for subdomain in that directive? I don't get how this is any different from URL rewrites.

Comment: I had same issue, have you found a solution?

Comment: Take a look this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34949564/881743

Comment: No I still haven't found a solution

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this, which has some dynamics and runs on .htaccess-level:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On

  # Web path to application root
  RewriteBase /

  # Set environment variables, also fetchable in PHP e.g. $_SERVER['CLIENT']
  SetEnvIf Host "^(.*)\.domain\.tld$" CLIENT=$1 APP_VERSION=1.0.0

  # Map some storage content to root, based on environment variable
  RewriteRule ^(storage/.*)$ clients/%{CLIENT}/$1 [QSA,L]

  # Forbid access to the other directories
  RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
  RewriteRule ^clients/ - [F,R=404,L]

  # No rewrite logic for physical files
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # Default route
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```